# How to call this SOAP API method in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I am testing an API in SOAP UI and it works fine. 
However, I have a problem in writing good PHP code to call this single method, others work fine.

Could you please give me some hints on how to call this method properly? There are no examples in documentation.

SOAP:

```
 <ser:DoChangeItemFieldsRequest>
 <ser:sessionId>sessionid</ser:sessionId>
 <ser:itemId>6768019561</ser:itemId>
 <!--Optional:-->
 <ser:fieldsToModify>
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <ser:item>
       <!--You may enter the following 10 items in any order-->
       <ser:fid>341</ser:fid>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <ser:fvalueString>{"sections":[{"items":[{"type":"TEXT","content":"zmiana tekstu"}]},{"items":[{"type":"IMAGE","url":"PHOTO_FID_16"}]}]}</ser:fvalueString>
       <!--Optional:-->

       <!--Optional:-->

       <!--Optional:-->

    </ser:item>
 </ser:fieldsToModify>
 <!--Optional:-->



</ser:DoChangeItemFieldsRequest>
```

PHP:

```
$parametry = array(
'sessionId' =>'7af4b0ce739992ed4f98dcc81df0d4d6f823fdbd0bcc68//00_1',
'itemId'=> 6768019561,
'fieldsToModify' => array (
array(
'fid' => 341,
'fvalueString' => '{"sections":[{"items":[{"type":"TEXT","content":"zmiana tekstu"}]},{"items":[{"type":"IMAGE","url":"PHOTO_FID_16"}]}]}'
                ))


);
$proba = $client->doChangeItemFields($parametry);
$proba2= $proba->changedItem;
```